# How to add custom settings to a Magento Product Meta Page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am new to Magento, just started working with it today.  I need to add a custom option to the Admin panel under the Meta Tab for a Product.  I need to add an option where the Admin can select to have this product removed from the Generated sitemap.xml file.

In wordpress this would be achieved with a Custom Meta field or a custom setting field.

Does a similar feature exist in Magento, to set custom settings and then retrieve them?  I saw something about Custom Attributes, but it appeared they actually showed up in the theme and panel, instead of working in the way I am describing?

User [Jürgen Thelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693207/jurgen-thelen) posted a very helpful snippet posted below that can help with the actual sitemap excluding part.

So I just need to figure out

1. How to add a setting to the Meta tab for a product
2. How to retrieve this settings value in my code below so that I can use it

The second part should be fairly straight forward, create a function to get all the product values that are set to be hidden in the sitemap.xml and then use them in the code below.

My main issue is adding the setting to the **Meta Information** area of the product admin page, any help please?

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    $products = array();

    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */

    if (!$store) {
        return false;
    }

    $urCondions = array(
        'e.entity_id=ur.product_id',
        'ur.category_id IS NULL',
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('ur.store_id=?', $store->getId()),
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('ur.is_system=?', 1),
    );
    $this->_select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('e' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName()))
        ->join(
            array('w' => $this->getTable('catalog/product_website')),
            'e.entity_id=w.product_id',
            array()
        )
        ->where('w.website_id=?', $store->getWebsiteId())
        // --- exclude single product by its entity_id
        ->where('e.entity_id<>152')
        // --- exclude multiple products by their entity_id's
        // ->where('e.entity_id NOT IN (?)', array(152, 156))
        ->joinLeft(
            array('ur' => $this->getTable('core/url_rewrite')),
            join(' AND ', $urCondions),
            array('url' => 'request_path')
        );

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');

    $query = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query($this->_select);
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $product = $this->_prepareProduct($row);
        $products[$product->getId()] = $product;
    }

    return $products;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Make yourself familiar how product properties are handled in magento ([product attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-attributes-work-in-magento)). To add your meta field to the product, you need to [create an attribute](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields) first. Then this attribute needs to be assigned to the attributeset of your product ([Adding attributes to attributesets](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-an-attribute-set)). The default attributeset will do. The new field will now be visible in your productconfiguration.
2. To access your new attribute you can call `$product->getData('your_attribute')` or `$product->getYourAttribute()` on a product object.